# SharePoint Online - Search box is not showing suggestions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, search-suggestion, search-box, sharepoint-search

I want to enable suggestions in global search box and search page search box.
Steps I followed :

1. Go to the More features page of the new **SharePoint admin center**, and sign in with an account that has admin permissions for your organization.
2. Under **Search**, select **Open**.
3. On the search administration page, select **Query Suggestion Settings --> Show Search Suggestion** is **enabled**.
4. From search box web part enabled the **"Show suggestions" property.** But search box is not showing result until I enabled the second option **"Show people name suggestions".** But in network panel its showing result only for "**PeopleNames**". Check second image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need help in **"How to enable search suggestions for search box for all results and not only for people name ? "**

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint automatically creates a query suggestion when you have clicked a search result for a query at least six times. For example, if you have entered the query word "test" and then clicked a search result six times, "test" automatically becomes a query suggestion.

Automatically query suggestions are generated daily for each result source and each site collection, so the query suggestions can be different for different result sources and site collections.

If you want to display query suggestions immediately, you could import suggest phrase from text file.

Same [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/620859/sharepoint-online-search-box-is-not-showing-sugges.html?childToView=621902#answer-621902) in the Q&A forum.
[image]

Comment: Hi @emily - Is there any other way to make it work ? I mean without importing from the text file ?

Comment: Hi @emily - Solution seems like manual approach and when you import query suggestions, any existing ones will be overwritten as mentioned in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-query-suggestions

I was looking for another approach as I mentioned in the question by enabling the query suggestion. It would be great if you can help me in that approach.

Comment: SharePoint query suggestion mechanism is that it automatically creates a query suggestion when you have clicked a search result for a query at least six times. For example, if you have entered the query word "test" and then clicked a search result six times, "test" automatically becomes a query suggestion.

Therefore, create a query suggestion, you should click a search result multiple times manually to let SharePoint automatically crawls.